# How can I reference a stack output value without building a dependency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have two CloudFormation stacks, one for `dynamodb` the other is for a `lambda`. The lambda works as `dynamodb stream target` so it needs to know the DynamoDB table stream ARN. So I exported the `arn` from `dynamodb` stack and referenced it in `lambda` stack.

It works well. However, it doesn't allow me to turn down `dynamodb` stack because there is a reference in the `lambda` stack. Is there a way for me to allow deleting the `dynamodb` stack even when there is a reference? I don't care whether the `lambda` works or not. There are some cases I need to turn the db table and create a new one.

Below is my `severless` configuration for adding dynamodb stream arn on lambda:

```
myHandler:
  handler: src/lambdas.myHandler
  name: myHandler
  events:
    - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        arn: 
          Fn::ImportValue: '${self:provider.dynamodbStackName}-tableStreamArn'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not with your current architecture. You can't delete a stuck which exports are used by other stacks (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html)):

> After another stack imports an output value, you **can't delete** the stack that is exporting the output value or modify the exported output value. All of the **imports must be removed** before you can delete the exporting stack or modify the output value.

If you don't want to tightly couple your stacks through export-import, you could remove the import/exports and pass the **DynamoDB table ARN as an parameter** to your lambda stack. This way you are not coupling the stacks, and you will be able to freely delete or update the DynamoDB stack.

You could also do it the other-way around, and pass your lambda's function name to your `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` as a parameter. Could be easier, as it seams that the function is more persistent then the DynanoDB table.

Comment: In your other option about `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping`, is it added to dyanmodb? What if dyanmodb doesn't exist?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao This is how you setup the stream between dynamodb and lambda? Did you do it some other way?

Comment: I set it up by attach dyanmodb stream arn on lambda. But this will bring a cross stack dependency. How do I pass lambda's function name to AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I don't understand how you could setup a stream between dynamodb and lambda without `EventSourceMapping`? Maybe we are thinking about different types of stream? Can you updated the question with your template showing the stream setup in CloudFormation?

Comment: I am using `serverless` framework to deploy it. It may use EventSourceMapping underneath. but I don't understand why you say it is a workaround.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately I don't know what how to make it in serverless framework. Workaround in a sense that'll you would have to change a design. But with serverless, I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: `serverless` is nothing more than a wrapper of cloudformation. I can use cloudformation if it works with your work around. But I don't quite understand how your workaround works. Could you give me more information about it?